# How to mention specific Git-folder within the master branch in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I would like to run jenkins job when the specific folder in Git/Git-hub master branch changes.

Currently its running whenever Git master is changing but i need only when the specific folder is changing within the Git master than only its supposed to run.

[image]

[image]

As I mentioned above,only subFolder changes than only I need to run the job,i tried with different options but its unable to identifying my folder.

Looking for you advice and solutions.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: This is is not possible. With git you need to checkout the hole rep.

Comment: Seems this plugin does not have such a feature. The plugin Gerrit Trigger can do the job but it's for repositories hosted by Gerrit. You could let the job be triggered but just exit if subFolder is not changed.

Comment: I dont think so its impossible.There might be a way to trigger the Jenkins job when git master branch folder is changes.

Comment: @ElpieKay, how can I implement your approach.Can you plz give me some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this question by adding one simple **Additional behavior** to the Jenkins i.e. just check '**Additional Behaviors**' section below the Git section and choose '**Polling using specific folder path**' that's it.

Now give the specific folder path whatever you want - in my case 'subFolder/*.sh'

Comment: Is this some plugin for this feature? Because in the current Jenkins version, I dont have this option there.

Answer (score 2):

One hack I can think of is in your jenkins test script, first read the latest commit (use the GIT_COMMIT environment variable), and scan for any change in the target sub-directory you care about. If no change shows up, then just terminate the build early.

It is not pretty, but should work in your scenario.

Example:

```bash
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT | grep "the/directory/you/care/" -q
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   # if there is no change under the directory you care, exit now.
   echo "No change under the target directory. Skipping build.."
   exit 0
fi

# your existing build/test script...
```

Comment: I am new to jenkins,can you plz give me one example?

Comment: I added an example of how the jenkins test script would look like.